# ArcMap Export maps for use in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml, arcgis, arcmap

I use the ArcMap 10.2 program in which I have several maps created with layers. I need to import these maps for use in Google Maps API v3. I have exported .kmz and .json among others, but when imported into the Google API not get to see the layers. This is a code example:

```
var spain = new google.maps.LatLng(40.3964129438718, -3.7129999999999654);
var mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapaSigaus"), {
        center: spain,
        zoom: 6
});

var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('URL/ESP_adm4.kmz');
kmzLayer.setMap(mapa);
```

What am I doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to load the file from your filesystem, or from a web url?
adding a kmz with google.maps.KmlLayer calls a service called KmlOverlayService, which decompresses the kmz and returns it back to you - this will not work with a local file.

I tried adding your file directly from the kmz [you linked](http://dosisproject.es/Minimo.kmz), and the load time via the KmlOverlayService was over 10s and failed to add to map. However, when I made a copy of your kmz in my [dropbox public folder](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5097876/Minimo.kmz), and I add to the map with:

```
var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5097876/Minimo.kmz',
    map: mapa
});
```

I get the kmz layer showing up as expected.[image]

(note that your original method for adding the kmz without the KmlLayerOptions object works fine in this situation as well.)

Comment: For what it's worth, exporting the data as geoJSON allows you to add from a local file by using: ```mapa.data.loadGeoJson('/path/to/my/file/Minimo.geojson');```. You don't get the symbology, but it's still an option.

Comment: Thank you, thank you ! You are a genious ! Indeed, it was that. It's about the path where the file is ... I do not understand is why you should have a server to read the file from Google Maps API ... is the response time?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the url in the [KmlLayerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayerOptions) object, like so:

```
var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'URL/ESP_adm4.kmz'});
```

You can assign the map in that way as well if you'd like:

```
var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url:'URL/ESP_adm4.kmz',
    map: mapa
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. No, this does not solve the problem ... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. the KMZ url needs to be a complete URL:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/ESP_adm4.kmz

([a relative URL returns a KmlStatus of `INVALID_REQUEST`](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=geoxml3_test/kmz/ESP_adm4.kmz))

2. the KMZ file needs to meet the restrictions of the Google Maps Javascript API KmlLayer renderer.  From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions):), those are:

> **Size and Complexity Restrictions for KML Rendering in Google Maps**
>
> Google Maps currently has specific limitations to the size and complexity of loaded KML files. Below is a summary of the current limits:
>
> **Note: these limits are temporary and are subject to change at any time.**
>
> - **Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)    3MB**
> - **Maximum uncompressed KML file size    10MB**
> - Maximum number of Network Links 10
> - Maximum number of total document-wide features  1,000

You didn't provide a link to your KMZ file, but based on the copy of the KMZ file of the same name at [gadm.org](http://www.gadm.org/), it is probably ~5 MB compressed KMZ, which is too big (it returns a KmlStatus of `DOCUMENT_TOO_LARGE` [for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/ESP_adm4.kmz).

If the file is being served from your local domain, you can use [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) to render it, but [may have performance issues (geoxml3 decompresses it to KML, then renders that KML as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/ESP_adm4.kmz), that is why google limits the size of the files they will render.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and your time. I pass the link to the specific file that I can not display: http://dosisproject.es/Minimo.kmz . It covers an area of 962kb, so I understand that is not a problem of size limit. What surprises me is that for example, in Google Maps Engine, the file can be displayed correctly: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=z5zZN3j5oKac.kX6C6EZw-b3U&usp=sharing

Comment: [Your file is returning a KmlStatus of `FETCH_ERROR`](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://dosisproject.es/Minimo.kmz).  If I copy [that file to my server, it works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/Minimo.kmz)

Comment: Exactly ... the problem is in the server and access. What have you configured to work well and not mine?